# can't print array in C using for loop

Tags: c, codeblocks

so i have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int a[10];
  int i= 0;

  for (i=0; i<11; ++i){
      a[i] = 0;
  }
  for(i=0; i<11; ++i){
      printf("%d", a[i]);
  }
}
```

i have read C by Dennis Ritchie book, and in my expectation it should print out like this

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but when it ran, just blank, nothing was printed
please help me solve my problem

Comment: Your code has an off-by-one error. Your loops should go while `i<10`, not `i<11`. Fix that and also tell me how you run this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared an array of 10 elements.

```
int a[10];
```

In this case the valid range of indices is `[0, 9]` that is if you have an array of `N` elements then the valid range of indices for the array is `[0, N-1]`.

Thus you need to change the loops in the porgram the following way

```
for (i=0; i< 10; ++i)
```

It is better either to define a manifest constant and to use it instead of the magic number 10 as for example

```
#define N 10

//...

int a[N];

for (i=0; i < N; ++i)
```

or at least to use in the loop expression

```
for (i=0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); ++i)
```

You could gain the same effect if you declare the array like

```
int a[10] = { 0 };
```

And insert after the last loop statement

```
puts( "" );
```

or

```
printf( "\n" );
```

Answer (score 1):

The output buffer has not been flushed to the console/terminal. Add this line after the `printf` loop

```
printf("\n");
```

Also, your array should be

```
int a[11];
```

so that the indexing remains in range.

Comment: The first thing shouldn't matter as all output streams are flushed on normal program termination.